# Need to make href dynamic

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap, jstl

```
<td><a href="<%=%>" target="_blank"id="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>"><s:property value="domainName" /></a></td>
```

it repeats multiple time as it is a column and the value needs to be dynamic with each domainName/objectName

I need to make this href dynamic and to do so i have made a map that stores

```
Hashmap<String objectName, String documentationLink>
```

is stored in MMTUtil.java

but Now I need to access the Hashmap to get the documentationLink in href tag using a objectName
my objectName in HashMap is equal to value="domainName" 
So what shall be the approach to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it in session or request attribute.
Example:

```
session.setAttribute("abc",hashMap);
else
request.setAttribute("abc",hashMap);
```

In the Jsp use

```
<%
Hashmap<String objectName, String documentationLink> hashmap = (HashMap<String objectName, String documentationLink>)request.getAttribute("abc);
%>
<a href='<%out.print(hashmap.get("domainName")'%>">link</a>
```

Comment: can I use session.getAttribute("abc");  
like this
    MMTUtil documentationLink = (MMTUtil) session.getAttribute(MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().get("objectName")); ?? I'm getting null pointer exception in this

Comment: you can use but you need to set it at code level before the request redirect to this page.